# CasperJS, cannot open URL from variable

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to be able to set inside a `casper.then` a specific url, to be opened in a later `casper.thenOpen`.
This is a sample mockup code that I set up to try it out: inside the `casper.then` function I will open a page and find the url to be opened.
How can I fix my code?
Thanks in advance!

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.base_uri = "https://www.google.it";

casper.start(casper.base_uri, function(){

    this.echo('Base URL: ' + this.getCurrentUrl());

});

casper.then(function(){

    // Here I will set the code to find the url to use: by now I am placing a fake one
    casper.base_uri = "https://www.google.fr"

});

casper.thenOpen(casper.base_uri, function () {

    this.echo('Changing URL to ' + casper.base_uri);
    this.echo('Current URL: ' + this.getCurrentUrl());

});

casper.run();
```

This is the result:

```
Base URL: https://www.google.it/
Changing URL to https://www.google.fr
Current URL: https://www.google.it/
```

Please help!
Paolo

Comment: In which way are you trying to find the url? Trying to find from page rendered?